# youtube extractor get dash Url -asynctask- android

Tags: android, android-studio, exoplayer

the error is mediaplayer Does not wait the asynctask to finish
the stream url is null , how i can fix that?

youtube extractor get dash Url wait time?

```
    String streamUrl;

        String youtubeLink = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdKrfyYfws8&list=RDOPU6ebpEPuA&index=5";
        new YouTubeExtractor(this) {
            @Override
            public void onExtractionComplete(SparseArray<YtFile> ytFiles, VideoMeta vMeta) {
                if (ytFiles != null) {
                    int itag = 22;
                     streamUrl = ytFiles.get(itag).getUrl();

                }
            }
        }.extract(youtubeLink, true, true);
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(streamUrl);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String streamUrl;

    String youtubeLink = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdKrfyYfws8&list=RDOPU6ebpEPuA&index=5";
    new YouTubeExtractor(this) {
        @Override
        public void onExtractionComplete(SparseArray<YtFile> ytFiles, VideoMeta vMeta) {
            if (ytFiles != null) {
                int itag = 22;
                 streamUrl = ytFiles.get(itag).getUrl();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(streamUrl);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.show();
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

            }
        }
    }.extract(youtubeLink, true, true);
```